# How can I convert a TTF (Font) for use on a Mac?

Tags: conversion, fonts

I need to convert a free ttf for use on a Mac - the best solution would be to convert it to otf so we can both use it. free solution for Windows preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TrueType fonts are supported directly on Mac OS X, as well as just about any other font type.  If you double click on the font, it should open in Font Book, and you can just choose "Install Font".

I do recommend Validating the font first, since Windows fonts do not always include everything necessary to fully use the font, but there is no reason you should have to convert the font...

Per Adobe ( http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/327/327791.html as of 2009-11-11) Mac OS X supports the following font formats:

```
.dfont
Multiple Master (Mac OS X 10.2 and later only)
OpenType (.otf)   *
TrueType (.ttf)   *
True Type Collection (.ttc)
Type 1 (PostScript)  *
```

Which I believe is the majority of the popular font formats... The fonts flagged with an asterisk are also natively supported on Windows....

Comment: I forgot to mention, I just tested this via, downloading a TTF font from (http://www.webpagepublicity.com/free-fonts.html), and didn't have any problems with Font Book recognizing the font...  (Font book is effectively the Fonts control panel on Mac OS X).

Answer (score 4):

just found a great website that does this and its free!

http://onlinefontconverter.com/

Answer (score 2):

or http://www.fontconverter.org

Answer (score 1):

Most TrueType fonts work on a Mac but some don't (some of the free ones). Use one of the font converters to change it to .otf

Comment: The question asks how to do that.  Saying to do it is not an answer.